# synchronising dashboard to sharepoint

Tags: dashboard

I have a dashboard that refreshes every one minute, and i want the data to be imported to share point automatically.
Can the data be synchronized by using VBA coding (which i am using for my dashboard). i am fine with synchronization with web links as well.

I am stuck with this, and if i clear this point my project will be completed.
Home some one comes with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of dashboard you have and where your data is stored and in what form, If you have Excel Dashboard using power pivot you can use excel services or power pivot services in SharePoint to publish it. If you have SQl reports you can implement performance point to create your own dashboard in SharePoint. 
Thank You